# How to delete Project server 2013 web app Administrative Time items

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013, project-server

I have MS Project Server 2013 and created Project Web App site

I have created multiple Administrative Time items now I want to

delete Administrative Time items but there is no option.

Answer (score 1):

From [Administrative Time (Project Server 2010 settings)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg982965(v=office.14).aspx):

> You can only delete categories that are not yet saved. For example,
>   let's say that you have created several new categories on the
>   Administrative Time page, but have not yet clicked Save on that page.
>   You can delete any of the new categories that you created while on
>   that page. Once you click Save on the Administrative Time page, the
>   categories that you added can no longer be deleted.

Same information in [Project Server 2013 Administrator's Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217892.aspx).